# How to prevent Spring Boot from parsing YAML keys with dots

Tags: yaml, spring-boot, snakeyaml

I have a YAML configuration file with a map of properties:

```yaml
properties:
  a.b.c: 1
```

Boot will parse this as:

```json
{a:{b:{c:1}}}
```

However, what I desire is :

```json
{'a.b.c': 1}
```

Is there anyway to coax it into "pass through" key mode? Quoting the key doesn't seem to help.

---

## Update

Actual example below.

### Java

```java
import static com.google.common.collect.Maps.newLinkedHashMap;

import java.util.Map;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.val;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties("hadoop")
public class HadoopProperties {

   private Map<Object, Object> properties = newLinkedHashMap();

}
```

### YAML

`application.yml`:

```yaml
hadoop:
   properties:
      fs.defaultFS: hdfs://localhost:8020
      mapred.job.tracker: localhost:8021
```

### Result

Calling `toString()` on the resulting object:

> HadoopProperties(properties={fs={defaultFS=hdfs://localhost:8020}, mapred={job={tracker=localhost:8021}}})

Comment: I'm not sure where you are seeing `{a:{b:{c:1}}}`. The normal usage of YAML in Spring Boot flattens it to `Properties` so it would only be one level deep. Can you show some code?

Comment: @DaveSyer updated to add actual code example

Comment: I see. It's because you are binding to a very generic object, so Spring Boot thinks your period separators are map key dereferences. What happens if you bind to `Map<String,String>` or `Properties`?

Comment: @DaveSyer Seems to work with `Map<String, Object>`, but not `Properties`. Thanks for the pointer!

Comment: I see the same problem, but I already have Map<String, Object> and still have the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I see. It's because you are binding to a very generic object, so Spring Boot thinks your period separators are map key dereferences. What happens if you bind to Map or Properties?

Answer (score 3):

you can use as below

```
hadoop:
   properties:
      "[fs.defaultFS]" : hdfs://localhost:8020
      "[mapred.job.tracker]": localhost:8021
```

reference - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070987/escaping-a-dot-in-a-map-key-in-yaml-in-spring-boot)