# Escaping a dot in a Map key in Yaml in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, key, yaml

I have a following yml config:

```
foo:
  bar.com:
    a: b
  baz.com:
    a: c
```

With a following class Spring tries to inject map with keys 'bar' and 'baz', treating dots as separator:

```
public class JavaBean {
    private Map<String, AnotherBean> foo;
(...)
}
```

I have tried quoting the key (i.e. 'bar.com' or "bar.com") but to no avail - still the same problem. Is there a way around this?

Comment: The reason quoting the key didn't help is because `bar.com:`, `"bar.com":` and `'bar.com':` (and `? bar.com`) all represent the same exact same thing in YAML and are all deserialized to the string `bar.com`. The dot doesn't signify anything special in YAML—the behavior you're seeing is happening in Spring after the YAML is deserialized.

Comment: So is SPring using YamlPropertiesFactoryBean behind the scenes? If so, is there any way to make it use YamlMapFactoryBean instead? :)

Answer (score 98, accepted):

A slight revision of @fivetenwill's answer, which works for me on Spring Boot 1.4.3.RELEASE:

```
foo:
  "[bar.com]":
    a: b
  "[baz.com]":
    a: c
```

You need the brackets to be inside quotes, otherwise the YAML parser basically discards them before they get to Spring, and they don't make it into the property name.

Comment: @shivakumar, this approach is still working for me, up through Spring Boot 2.1.7.RELEASE. Not sure what to suggest to you, other than reviewing the [Relaxed Binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.8.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding) documentation, as some of the rules changed somewhat in Spring Boot 2. See also: [Spring Boot 2 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#relaxed-binding)

Answer (score 12):

This should work:

```
foo:
  "[bar.com]":
    a: b
  "[baz.com]":
    a: c
```

Inspired from [Spring Boot Configuration Binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-Configuration-Binding#map-based-binding) Wiki

Answer (score 4):

This is not possible if you want automatic mapping of yaml keys to Java bean attributes. Reason being, Spring first convert YAML into properties format. 
See section 24.6.1 of link below:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

So, your YAML is converted to:

```
foo.bar.com.a=b
foo.baz.com.a=c
```

Above keys are parsed as standard properties.

As a work around, you can use Spring's `YamlMapFactoryBean` to create a Yaml Map as it is. Then, you can use that map to create Java beans by your own.

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    private Map<String, Object> foo;

    @Bean
    public Map<String, Object> setup() {
        foo = yamlFactory().getObject();
        System.out.println(foo); //Prints {foo={bar.com={a=b}, baz.com={a=c}}}
        return foo;
    }

    @Bean
    public YamlMapFactoryBean yamlFactory() {
        YamlMapFactoryBean factory = new YamlMapFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(resource());
        return factory;
    }

    public Resource resource() {
        return new ClassPathResource("a.yaml"); //a.yaml contains your yaml config in question
    }

}
```

Comment: Any way to make the YamlMapFactoryBean return a map of certain Bean instances instead of map of maps? Any way to return a map from a specific configuration node? My yml is more complicated, the map config is just a part of it and I'd rather not separate just map config to separate config. The above code is hackish enough for me :)

Comment: I agree with you. Above code is a bit of work around. But to gain maximum out of spring auto configuration, I fear you will have to give up dots in your yaml keys. Otherwise, in setup() method above, you can iterate the yaml object and create beans manually (this may cause issues with auto-wiring).

Comment: Yeah I understand. Still I will try to lookup how Spring autowires this and maybe there is a way to make it autowire from map instead of from properties :)

Comment: The URL points to the current version, which is not the same as when this was posted 8 years ago. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.7.17/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.yaml.mapping-to-properties for a kinda "permalink".