# What is indexed array in YAML?

Tags: yaml

In my yaml spring-boot application config I have

```
additional-properties[auto.register.schemas]: false
additional-properties[use.latest.version]: true
```

and it works! I haven't found this syntax in the YAML specification. What does it mean? How can it be re-written using standard YAML? Is this the same as

```
additional-properties:
    - auto.register.schemas: false
    - use.latest.version: true
```

?

Comment: This could be a [map binding](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.18.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-relaxed-binding-maps) according to the docs. It's certainly nothing YAML knows of. Can you give details about *how* „it works“?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting and after finding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42285949/1259360), I conclude that (at least in Spring `application.yaml`):

```
camel.component.kafka:
         additional-properties[auto.register.schemas]: false
         additional-properties[use.latest.version]: true
```

is equivalent to

```
camel.component.kafka.additional-properties:
            "[auto.register.schemas]": false
            "[use.latest.version]": true
```

and this is equivalent to

```
camel:
   component:
      kafka:
         additional-properties:
            "[auto.register.schemas]": false
            "[use.latest.version]": true
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK:
Every element (separated by a dot) has to be on its own line and tabed accordingly.

```
foo:
   bar:
       name: value
       name2: value2
   fez: value
```

So your example would be:

```
additional-properties:
    auto:
       register:
           schemas: false
```

Comment: This is not true, at least not for Spring `application.yaml`. And the second part is not true either, see my answer.