# How to read .yml file according to a passed parameter and how to set a default value if parameter does not match in Springboot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, yaml

Is there a way I can pass a parameter to specify which list in "APP" / "WEB" I like to get? e.g. getting [abc.com, efg.com] when I pass "APP" as parameter. And can I have a Default result when none of them is matched against that parameter? Thank you.

I get the .yml file as Map with below code

```
url:
  filter:
  APP:
    - abc.com
    - def.com
  ...
  WEB:
    - ghi.com
    - jkl.com

  /*DEFAULT?*/
```

I only want to get the list inside "APP" or "WEB" according to the parameter passed if there can be any. But right now I have to get the whole filter as map before I get the list I want. And I don't know how to make a Default list if parameter is not "APP" nor "WEB"

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="url")
public class UrlConfig {
    private Map<String,List<String>>filter;

    public Map<String, List<String>> getFilter() {
        return filter;
    }

    public List<String> getFilterByDevice(String device){
        return getFilter().get(device);
    }
}
```

In getFilter(), I get the result as below. By getFilterByDevice(device), I get the List according to the device but I have to get the whole map in getFilter() first. Is there a way not to get the whole map before getting the list I want?

```
{APP=[abc.com, def.com], WEB=[ghi.com, jkl.com]}
```

This is where I get the value, device has to be read from a method:

```
private void filter(device){
List<String> filter = UrlConfig.getFilterByDevice(device);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what your problem is. You say you want to pass `"APP"` as parameter to get the list `[abc.com, efg.com]`, then you show the function `getFilterByDevice` which seems to do exactly that. Obviously, if your data is in a map, you need to access the map in order to access the data. I don't understand how you'd want to access the data without accessing the map.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I mean that can I get a specific list without getting the whole map? And can I set a default list in yml file if the parameter passed is not APP or WEB?

Comment: You can put a `DEFAULT` key there and do `filter.getOrDefault(device, filter.get("DEFAULT"))`. But I still don't understand what you want with „without getting the whole map“. By using `getFilterByDevice` you already don't get the whole map. Inside its implementation you can access `filter` directly instead of doing `getFilter`. Is that what you mean? Maybe explain how the solution you wish for differs in effects.

Comment: I wish that in getFilterByDevice, "someLogic" can get the List in "APP" or "WEB" directly from yml file without using Hashmap.get() cause I do not want to have the whole "filter" map in the first place :) I don't know if this is possible.
public List<String> getFilterByDevice(String device){
       List<String> filter = someLogic(device);
        return filter;
    }

Comment: If there's a mapping in YAML, there's gonna be a Map in your Java data. You can scrap it early by using a variation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34082891/347964) where you remove the `filter` map from the original object and select the appropriate child, maybe that is what you're searching for. Or maybe what you actually want is to split your configuration file into multiple files and provide the parts in `WEB` or `APP` depending on the deployment target?